# What keywords to learn more about sense pleasing?

Tags: emotion, sensation, aesthetics

The article [What Makes Something Aesthetically Pleasing? | Simple Minded](https://www.simpleminded.life/what-makes-aesthetically-pleasing/) lists some way to pleasing your [senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense):

- **Vision:** balance, emphasis, rhythm, proportion, pattern, unity and contrast. Along with the visual elements: color, line, shape, value, texture
- **Hearing:** loudness, pitch, beat, repetition, melody, pattern, noise
- **Touch:** texture, shape, weight, softness, temperature, vibration, sharpness
- **Smell:** sweet, fruity, fragrant, pungent, chemical, woody, minty
- **Taste:** umami, sweetness, sourness, bitterness, texture, pungency

If I want to learn more about **sense pleasing**, where should I start? Which subfields within psychology or neuroscience research about this? The Wikipedia page of [Sensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense) doesn't contain the keyword `pleasing`. Searching on Google Scholar with the keyword [`sense pleasing`](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=sense+pleasing&btnG=) doesn't yield anything. Two other fields relevant to this are aesthetics and design, but they are just applications of this concept.

Comment: Why not go to the beginning and scholar search "aesthetically pleasing" or "aesthetically please"?

Comment: There are many reasons: (1) initial searches didn't yield anything. (2) Still, I'm reading on other topics in aesthetics that may related to it. (3) I must confess that I feel like only psychology and neuroscience can provide a "legitimate" answer. For one, temperature sense does exists, but I don't think aesthetics be aware of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me is that sense pleasing is better recognized by the term "**[rewarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reward_system) stimuli**":

> stimuli that the brain interprets as intrinsically positive and desirable or as something to approach

Obviously rewarding stimuli isn't necessarily about sensual stimuli, but that would be a good start.